# There are no SQL services running or even showing up after SQL Server installation

Tags: sql-server, installation, windows-10, ssms-2012

I have installed SQL Server 2012 on my Windows 10 machine. Though it shows installed but there are no SQL Server services running or even showing up. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Re-install SSMS from the start.
May be because of the network you're facing this problem.